# document.location.replace base URL inside callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have the following site structure which consists of an outer page (*page1.html*) with an iframe containing *page2.html*:

```
/mysite/page1.html            
/mysite/folder1/page2.html
```

- *page1.html* contains a function that takes a callback

.

```
function myMethod(callback) {

    var btn = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
    btn.innerHTML = 'Resolve';

    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        callback();
    });   
}
```

- *page2.html* calls up to the main page to invoke `myMethod()`

.

```
top.myMethod(function () {
    document.location.replace('page2.html');
});
```

However this results in a 404 as the redirect resolves to `/mysite/page2.html`.

Debugging `document.location` inside the callback prior to `replace()` refers to the correct page (*page2.html*).

**1. Why does the call to `replace()` resolve the base url to be the
    parent page location and not the location the callback is defined?**

**2. How can I make the call to `replace()` respect the location it is
    defined?**

*Notes:
The example given is obviously a simplified version of the real issue. Also if anyone could suggest a way to replicate the site structure using something like jsFiddle I will try to provide a concrete example.*

Comment: Do you want to redirect the parent window or the iframe? (super hacky fidder I made up http://jsfiddle.net/rmck0dxt/)

Comment: Yes the expected behaviour is for the iframe to reload with iframecontent.html